# What will happen in ConcurrentDictionary if there is a collusion on try add and remove?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

In my BL, I want that a certain code will not be executed while another thread is already in progress.

The issue is that the code can be executed (by demand) once for each customer but not twice  for the same customer

I have used the C# `ConcurrentDictionary` to keep track of the customers already in progress and when the execution is finished i have removed them from the `ConcurrentDictionary`, what will happen if when im trying to remove customer id from the `ConcurrentDictionary` while another thread is trying to add (the same or different key)? Is the `ConcurrentDictionary` locks for write and the try remove will fail?

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, DateTime> m_customerInProgress = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, DateTime>();

public void ExecuteLogic(int customerId)
{
        if (m_customerInProgress.TryAdd(customerId, DateTime.Now) == false)
        {
            this.Log().Info("customer in progress ");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Log().Info("DoSomething failed ");
        }
        finally
        {
            DateTime startDateTime;

            if (m_customerInProgress.TryRemove(customerId, out startDateTime) == false)
            {
                this.Log().Fatal("this should never happens");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Log().Info("customer finished execution");
            }
        }
}
```

Can the `this.Log().Fatal("this should never happens");` ever happen?

What will happen if the try add and try remove will execute in the same time for the same key?

What will happen if it will execute for different keys?

Comment: [Code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L436) (if it helps).

Comment: You have implemented a concurrent locking mechanism which will work fine. `TryAdd` and `TryRemove` are both atomic operations on the collection.

Comment: my question is,if the tryremove will fail due to race condition on the lock of the ConcurrentDictionary this will result in a deadlock for the user on this function (becuse he will forever be in the ConcurrentDictionary ), can it happens ? can the remove fail due to race cndition

Comment: Only one thread will successfully add `customerId` and continue, deleting it at the end. Unless there are other methods what can run in parallel and somehow delete that `customerId` the "this should never happens" should never occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. The `TryAdd` will only succeed if the `TryRemove` has completed.

The only odd thing you may see is that after the `TryRemove` returns the thread (lets call it `T1`) is suspended, and then another thread (lets call that `T2`) calls your method. It may execute the entire method before `T1` resumes execution, so your logging could become intertwined.

Comment: my question is,if the tryremove will fail due to race condition on the lock of the ConcurrentDictionary this will result in a deadlock for the user on this function (becuse he will forever be in the ConcurrentDictionary ), can it happens ? can the remove fail due to race cndition

Comment: @eliavra - The only way for the `TryRemove` to fail is if the items isn't in the dictionary in the first place. The structure of your code means you'll only end up calling `TryRemove` if `TryAdd` succeeded. There's no race condition.